# Inserting more values at the same row

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a table for a restaurant where i save an order with the "code" (basically the name of the dish), "table" and price in the DB, the "table" is the primary key. But now im strugling in how to add new orders for the same "table". lets say a client decide to order a desert or a drink, how can i put the values "code" and "price" into the table without rewrinting the previous values?

Comment: This is where "database normalization" would come into play. Make another table for items, where each item is another row. Have an order_id or table_id in the table to reference it back to the original table.

Comment: Hi - just following up. Was your question answered satisfactorily? If there is more we can help with, please add a comment below one of the answers, or edit your question to clarify what else you need help with. Otherwise, it would be great if you could choose a "best answer" *(by clicking the checkmark beside the answer)* to close out the question.

Comment: Hi Kalil - following up again. Could we trouble you to select a best answer -- or provide you own and select that -- to close out the question? That would help us out. *Many Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas for you:

*You are using the term `table` to refer to a table of people who are ordering stuff. Because this could be confusing in my answer, let's use the term `customer` to refer to the table full of customers who are placing orders.*

First, you must decide how to structure your database and tables.

One idea is to have two SQL tables: (a) A table of dishes (entres, desserts, drinks, etc) and their prices, (b) A table of transactions. (Each dish ordered is a single transaction, so there will multiple transactions for each customer)

Each transaction (one row) will include:

a. transactionIndex - sequential - autoIncremented - UNIQUE (primary key)

b. transactionID - invoice_number - could just be YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS

c. table_num - integer (identifies the customer(s) who made the orders)

d. dish - the dish that was ordered

When you print the invoice, you search the Tn table for all items related to transactionID #123. Makes it very easy to add new orders.

If desired, you can also have a SQL table of ***sessions***, which can reference all transactions involved in a single dining session. Essentially, this will be a record of each completed invoice. You might have fields like:

a. SessionIdx - unique index, auto-incrementing, primary key

b. SessionID - the invoice number - will be the transaction_num in the transactions table

c. date/time

d. number of customers

e. payment method

Also note that you will want to make this a relational database, which simply means that instead of writing the name of the dish, and the price of the dish, in their own fields in the *transactions table* - you just put the dish_id (from your SQL table of dishes). Then, the dishes table will be polled to get the dish name and dish price. Makes it easy to update things. *However, you also might wish to store historical prices so that when prices are updated you do not lose the historical price data.*

Answer (score 0):

I think that you chose bad primary key. Because table cant be a primary key in DB. Because you have to use table multiple times for orders.

You have 2 options:

1. if you want table as primary key, you have to create new DB table for every table and there store every order for it. Above of it you can store DB table with tables
2. Choose Orders as primary key. And assign table for every order.

Thats my opinion

Comment: Changing the primary key will suffice for now, later when updating the service i think i will have to use gibberish's suggestion. Thanx guys